# Android URL intent: browser is very slow to open

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, android-intent, start-activity

In our app, by clicking on a button, we need to open a website in the browser

```
    Intent openBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(openBrowserIntent);
```

We are finding that the browser takes ages to open, maybe because the link contains some redirects?

Is there any parameter in the intent, to force the browser to open as soon as we click? Otherwise, the user will see nothing happening for 2-3 seconds

Comment: you can implement webview in your app to reduce time and load page quickly if its just a webpage

Comment: unfortunately we need to redirect to the browser

Comment: what about direct intent for chrome browser ?

Comment: @Quicklearner how is it?

Comment: you should test the same in different devices to check the response time

Comment: i will add an answer and let me know

Comment: unfortunately, no speed improvement

Comment: Alright , Test it on different devices too , the device ram plays an important role also

Comment: I have a Google Pixel 2, so I don't think the RAM is an issue there

Answer (score 0):

> We are finding that the browser takes ages to open, maybe because the link contains some redirects?

You could test this by trying a URL to a simpler site, one that does not involve redirects, and seeing how quickly it opens. You could also test this by replacing the `Intent` with one that just starts up an ordinary activity in some other app (e.g., Settings). This will help you narrow down:

- Is starting any other app slow? If yes, then the issue is tied to the device (free system RAM, CPU, etc.)
- Is starting the browser slow for anything? If yes, then there is very little that you can do about it, though note that performance will vary by browser, and there are many Web browsers for Android
- Is having the browser display this particular URL slow? If so, fix the site to be less slow. In many cases, this will have benefits beyond just the speed in which your Android browser shows the page, such as helping users who visit this page by other means.

> Is there any parameter in the intent, to force the browser to open as soon as we click?

No, there is no `EXTRA_COULD_YOU_PLEASE_OPEN_QUICKLY_KTHXBYE` or similar extra. Likewise, there is no `FLAG_ACTIVITY_AW_COME_ON_GET_MOVING_ALREADY` flag. You could try replacing your current action with `android.intent.action.VIEW_NOW_NOW_NOW`, but I suspect that it will just result in an `ActivityNotFoundException`. :-)

Comment: It's very very strange, I have a Google Pixel 2, so I don't think the RAM and CPU are an issue the there. I tried with other urls, and the opening is still very slow. I also tried with an "old" Nexus 5X, and opening the browser activity is slow there too.
I remember, with the same app, opening a url on the browser used to be rather fast. Very strange.

Comment: However it does look like, for different pages, the browser opening time varies. So the faster the page, the quicker the browser opens. I wish it was possible to open the browser as soon as you click, but it seems like Android doesn't provide this.

Comment: @DanieleB: The redirects are not helping the case. Android needs to make `HEAD` requests to get the MIME type, in order to fully craft the `Intent`, and the redirects result in several `HEAD` requests. You might try `setDataAndType()` instead of providing the `Uri` in the `Intent` constructor and see if that allows Android to bypass those `HEAD` requests, if you're fairly certain that this URL will always wind up at some Web page.

Comment: I just tried: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html"); startActivity(intent);` but the loading time is the same. I decided to show a progress on the toolbar just after the click, so at least this gives a feedback to the user, telling to wait. Many thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> Direct intent for chrome browser

```
String urlString="URL_HERE";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Chrome browser app not installed
    intent.setPackage(null);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this is your intent to choose browser first then load page on selection

```
    Intent openBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(openBrowserIntent);
```

**Please test both the cases and on different devices too**

Comment: What about users who do not want to use Chrome? What about users who do not *have* Chrome?

Comment: The requirement is pretty clear , to load URL and there is a workaround in catch block it will ask the user to choose browser in that case if there is no chrome browser

Comment: You are handling the "do not have Chrome" scenario. You are not handling the "do not want to use Chrome" scenario.

Comment: Well Chrome seems to be a perfect browser , as now it loads pretty fast and uses cache , One would actually go for it . Most of the Stock and Customized OS has chrome pre-installed in it ,nobody wouldnt mind to not asking the browser first